# Derivation of the magnetic field on the axis of a circular loop at a point very far away from the Centre

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

When studying about the basics of electromagnetism, I came across the formula for the magnetic field due to a current carrying loop at a point on the axis that lies on the plane of the loop
My book(https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?leph1=4-8) (pg161) has derived this by simply saying it's analogous to an electric dipole , however that's not very rigourous ,so I tried deriving it myself, which is where I'm struggling.
I'd really appreciate some help. I have shown what I tried below

As we move away from the loop, the loop seems to collapse onto a line.

now from biot-savats law

db= $\mu$Idl Rsin $\theta$/(4$\pi$ ${R}^{3}$)

at a point far away from the wire, sin$\theta$ is approximately 90 degrees
so the equation becomes $\mu$Idl R/(4$\pi$ ${R}^{3}$)
as we want the field to be in terms of the magnetic moment, we multiply and divide by $\pi$ ${R}^{2}$

therefore we end up with $\mu$Idl R m/(4$\pi$*$\pi$ ${R}^{4}$)

which is obviously wrong

where am I going wrong? I would also like to apologize for typing things like $\pi$*$\pi$ instead of $\pi$}^{2} and other formatting errors as I'm not able to write some equations  in mathsJaX

Note: - I seem to have forgotten to mention what the symbols mean

m-magnetic moment

$\mu$:- permeability of free space

$\theta$ :- angle between the current element and the position vector

I- current

dB= Differential magnetic field

Comment: I would like to apologize for any formatting, spelling, or grammar errors.

Comment: Holy crap friend,  you can use the `$`…`$` one pair per expression,  you don't have to put them around everything individually just enclose the whole expression, with one at each end! Also more tips on formatting [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I'll look into that thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop 'collapses' into *two* lines: the nearer side and the farther side, with currents in opposite directions. So you need to be more careful with the distance, since the two sides produce fields in opposite directions, tending to cancel.  Write out the line element $dl$ as a vector and likewise $R$ and evaluate the cross product before approximating.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!